# Understanding background processes/agents in Windows Phone 8 (Chatterbox VoIP)

Tags: windows-phone-8, voip

I've been developing a VoIP app based on Chatterbox for a little while now, but there are still a few things that I can't quite fully wrap my head around, one of which is the handling of the background process.

So it appears that every time the UI comes to the foreground, BackgroundProcess.ConnectUI() is called, which in turn calls VoIPBackgroundProcess.Launch(). Does this mean that a new background process is created every time I minimize and resume the app? Or rather, I've seen that when a call is not in progress, the backgroundprocessID returned is different after each minimize-resume, but when a call IS in progress, it returns the same. What causes this behavior?

My real question is this: I need to have a C/C++ thread (a network stack) running the entire time my application is active, or rather, past the Login page. I have a class that manages this thread, and the Globals class holds a reference to this class. I can start the thread, and it runs just fine. When a call is in place, and I minimize-resume the app, the thread continues to run. However, when a call is not in place and I minimize-resume, the thread stops running. What can I do to ensure that this thread runs freely in a background process no matter the state of the call status?

I'd appreciate any help on this matter. I'm hoping its something simple that I've overlooked.